# How to set focus on a dropdown checklist(ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using `ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js` to convert my normal dropdownlist into a dropdownlist with checkboxes.When I'm use the ID of the original dropdownlist to set the focus using javascript it does not work. I understand that the plugin alters the original component dynamically, so I was looking for a way to accomplish setting focus on dropdwnlist, not sure if there's a special way to do it.

My html sort of looks like this :

```
<select name ='location_name' id = 'location_name' multiple="multiple">
    <option value ="Select">Select</option>
    <option value ="London">London</option>
    <option value ="New York">New York</option>
</select>
```

Then I am using the plugin for converting it into set of checkboxes :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
<script>
  $("#location_name").dropdownchecklist( {icon: {},  width:180, maxDropHeight: 350} );
</script>
```

After conversion I'm trying to set the focus with no luck :

```
document.getElementById("location_name").focus(); // does not work
```

Ref :

> ```
> https://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html
> ```

Comment: Could you supply where could we can find `ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js` ?

Comment: edited my question, included a link at the bottom for dropdownchecklist.

Comment: I tried to make a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) demo, but it does not work. http://jsbin.com/petipeveso/1/